# dict in python with key-values, for values have one variable included

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict in python with key values and for values I have one variable included in it . I want to change the value of variable at run time. How to do that as it initializes the dict at inital.

Suppose it is as:

```
number = ""
dict = { "a": ["welcome" + number + " Back"] }   # number = ""
```

Now if I do as `number = 45` somehow calculated. I want to auto-update the dict to as :

```
dict={ "a" :["welcome" + number + " Back"] }    # number = 45
```

But dict is updated at initial stage and it is not changing value of number at run time.

Comment: You cannot add strings and numbers.

Comment: If i have used a list inside dict that means there must be other elements in list which i ll be using. So that's why I am concatenating it with that number making it as one element only

Comment: and why is it down voted may i know

Answer (score 3):

`int`s are immutable in Python, but you could do a similar thing with a mutable structure, like a `list`:

```
>>> number = [""]
>>> d={"a":["welcome Back", number]} 
>>> d
{'a': ['welcome Back', ['']]}
>>> number[0] = 45
>>> d
{'a': ['welcome Back', [45]]}
```

In this case the `dict` contains a reference to the mutable `list`, so the `dict` is updated when the `list` changes.

Comment: If i have used a list inside dict that means there must be other elements in list which i ll be using. So that's why I am concatenating it with that number making it as one element only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of self-referencing dictionary values I'd recommend you just use [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) instead.

Anyway, here's a possible way to achieve what you want:

```
dct = {
    "a": lambda: ["welcome {} back".format(dct["number"])],
    "number": ""
}

for number in ["one", "two", "three"]:
    dct["number"] = number
    print(dct["a"]())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list of list

```
    >>> n = ['']
    >>> d = {'a': ["welcome", n, "back"]}
    >>> d
    {'a': ['welcome', [''], 'back']}
    >>> n[0] = 45
    >>> d
    {'a': ['welcome', [45], 'back']}
```